# emacs org mode to beamer: how to do multicolumn text

Tags: emacs, org-mode, beamer

I'm trying to display two columns of itemizes next to each other on a beamer document written in emacs org mode. For the export, I followed this tutorial: http://emacs-fu.blogspot.com/2009/10/writing-presentations-with-org-mode-and.html

I tried to include latex code in the document

```
\begin{columns}
\column{0.45\textwidth}
- topic
    - subtopic
    - sub
- topic
\column{0.45\textwidth}
- topic
- topic
\end{columns}
```

This put the columns next to each other as wanted, but the list inbetween was just plain text in a single line. As I use org mode to avoid writing all the latex code by hand, I tried a couple of tutorials.

They all suggested something like

```
*** list heading
:OPTIONS:
:BEAMER_col: 0.45
:END:
<content>
```

Which was completely ignored in my output. When I insert tags like :BCOL: after the heading, they get displayed as plain text on the resulting slides
When I moved the :END: down like this:

```
*** list heading
:OPTIONS:
:BEAMER_col: 0.45
<content>
:END:
```

then sometimes the headings got moved to columns. I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong, if the tutorials are outdated, or if my emacs version is.
I don't have administrative access to the machine here, and don't think I can talk the admin into updating 1000+ machines just for my document ;-)

Other beamer environments like :BEAMER_env: block get ignored, too.

Emacs 23.4.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 2.24.10) of 2012-09-08 on trouble, modified by Debian

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 8):

The following does work for me (with Org 8).

```
* Slide

** Col left                                                             :BMCOL:
   :PROPERTIES:
   :BEAMER_col: 0.45
   :END:

- topic
    - subtopic
    - sub
- topic

** Col right                                                            :BMCOL:
   :PROPERTIES:
   :BEAMER_col: 0.45
   :END:

- topic
- topic
```

See http://screencast.com/t/snlR2ii0xTZ for the results.

Comment: Weird, this gives me two slides titled "Col left" and "Col right".  Has something changed, or do I need header options?

Comment: Ah, the interaction with the `#+OPTIONS:   H:1` is important, solved.  I had `H:2`, hence `* Section`, `** Slide`, `*** Column`.  It seems that the tag `BMCOL` is now called `B_column` (though the old tag still works) and can be added to a header using `C-c C-b c`.

Answer (score 5):

And if you want to have the columns vertically aligned at the top, add `:BEAMER_opt: [t]`, as in the example below.  Use `:BEAMER_opt: [T]` instead if your columns include graphics.

```
* Slide

** Col left                                                           :BMCOL:
   :PROPERTIES:
   :BEAMER_col: 0.45
   :BEAMER_opt: [t]
   :END:

- topic
    - subtopic
    - sub
- topic

** Col right                                                          :BMCOL:
   :PROPERTIES:
   :BEAMER_col: 0.45
   :BEAMER_opt: [t]
   :END:

- topic
- topic
```